# Finding the index of the first repeating item in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, hashmap

I was solving an arrays problem from GFG, where we need to find the index of the first repeating element. The question is as follows:
**Given an array arr[] of size n, find the first repeating element. The element should occur more than once and the index of its first occurrence should be the smallest.**

I tried to use the hashmaps in python to go ahead with the problem. The following are my two codes:

**Code Snippet 1**

```
class Solution:
    #Function to return the position of the first repeating element.
    def firstRepeated(self,arr, n):
        m = {}
        for i in arr:
            if i not in m:
                m[i] = 1
            else:
                m[i] += 1
        for i in arr:
          if m[i] > 1:
            return arr.index(i)+1
        
        return -1
```

**Code Snippet 2**

```
class Solution:
    #Function to return the position of the first repeating element.
    def firstRepeated(self,arr, n):
        m = {}
        for i in arr:
            if i not in arr:
                m[i] = 1
            else:
                m[i] += 1
        for i in arr:
          if m[i] > 1:
            return arr.index(i)+1
        
        return -1
```

Code snippet 2 runs just fine but not code snippet 1. In code snippet 2, I have traversed through the array while in the former one, I have traversed the hashmap. When I tried in colab, both the codes are giving the correct answers. Not able to understand why they took the arr and not the hashmap m.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
Am I missing something? Both snippets look the same

Comment: how both code work fine , when your second code is worng.  how you are able to increment `m[i]+=1` when it is not first initiased in the dictionary iteself.

Comment: Isn't snippet 1 the working one and snippet 2 the failing one?

Comment: @AndreCanilho `not in m` vs `not in arr`.

Comment: What does *"they took the arr and not the hashmap m"* mean?

Answer (score 2):

### Updated answer

Your code snippets only differ in one word i. e. using `arr` (the array) in your second snippet instead or `m` (the dictionary) in your first.

By reason of that your first snippet will run and return a correct result (assuming you want a 1-based index; for 0-based index remove the `+1`) while your second snippet will fail with a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

#### Why will snippet #2 fail with [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError)?

Well, you're looping over the array and then check for every element in the array whether it's in the array or not. This check doesn't make any sense, since the element is guaranteed to be in the array, otherwise you wouldn't receive the value within the `for` loop.

Consequently, the condition `if i not in arr:` will always be `false` which results in the the value at `m[i]` never being initialized and the `else` branch always being executed. Due to the missing initialization there is no key `i` in the dictionary `m` which you could increase by 1 (see line `m[i] += 1`) and therefore a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) is thrown.

#### Additonal remarks

You do have one unused parameter `n` which you can remove, since you don't need the array size as a parameter in Python.

---

> The rest of the post can be ignored and is only left there to have some kind of version history and explanation for the discussion in the comment section.

---

### Edit #1

As some comments by [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) indicate I need to explain my original answer in more detail:

##### Comment 1: *Fails for example input `[10, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]`, reporting the `3` instead of the `5`*

Good point. I did not think of that. However, I think this is a specification problem. *[...] find the first repeating element [...]* `(positionFirst, positionRepeated)` could be interpreted in two ways:

Consider `[10, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]`:

- `(1, 5)` with `positionFirst` being minimal (the first value of the pair is encountered first)
- `(2, 4)` with `positionRepeated` being minimal (this is the first pair to be encountered)

I've used the latter interpretation, in which case, the output is not wrong.

##### Comment #2: *It's `O(n)`, since `index()` is called only once*

For better understanding: this was proposed by [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) and was found to be much faster (approx. 1.5-2 times faster).

```py
from time import time
# my proposed solution
def with_enumerate(arr):
    encountered_elements = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(arr):
        if value in encountered_elements:
            return encountered_elements[value]
        encountered_elements[value] = i
    return -1

# solution proposed by Kelly Bundy
def with_index(arr):
    encountered_elements = set()
    for value in arr:
        if value in encountered_elements:
            return arr.index(value)
        encountered_elements.add(value)
    return -1
# The max_value variable was introduced by me to allow for better comparison
max_value = 10000 
arr = [*range(max_value), 0]

funcs = with_enumerate, with_index

for f in funcs * 3:
    t = time()
    for _ in range(100):
        f(arr)
    print(round((time()-t)*10, 3), f.__name__)
```

Sample output:

```
1.76 with_enumerate
0.747 with_index
1.011 with_enumerate
0.619 with_index
0.922 with_enumerate
0.594 with_index
```

Yes, I should have been more precise here. I assumed someone was using just `index()` without any set or dictionary which would result in a runtime of `O(n²)`. If you use `index()` together with a set or dictionary you would of course also get a runtime of `O(n)`. But that implementation does not make much sense (from an algorithmic point of view), because you are already storing the encountered values, why not also store their position then? Instead you use `index()` to compute that position again. That would be a second loop over the array which is not necessary.

Here also comes my second observation into play in how you measured the performance. By setting up the array like this

```py
max_value = 10
arr = [*range(max_value), 0] 
# results in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

you made sure that the linear search by `index()` will always be successful on the first element which is the best case of `O(1)`.

If you instead setup the array that the duplicate would occur late in the array which is the worst case (and I was talking about the worst case):

```py
max_value = 10
arr = [*range(max_value), max_value - 1] 
# results in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
```

the measurements look a lot different since the linear search will now have the worst case runtime of `O(n)`. I again used a `max_value` of `10000`:

```
1.851 with_enumerate
1.035 with_index
1.246 with_enumerate
1.29 with_index
1.11 with_enumerate
0.984 with_index
```

One can already see, that the two versions are now much closer together.

Now, there is another thing we need to have a look at if we wanna properly compare both algorithms: You are using `index()` which is implemented in `C` and is therefore of course faster than the interpreted Python. If we were to replace the `lst:index()` method with the following functionally equivalent Python function `index()`

```py
def index(arr, value):
    for i, arrValue in enumerate(arr):
        if arrValue == value:
            return i
    return -1
```

so that the line `return arr.index(value)` will end up being `index(arr, value)`
and then measure again with a `max_value` of `10000` the results turn in favor of my implementation (especially for larger `n`):

```
1.906 with_enumerate
1.189 with_index
0.915 with_enumerate
1.011 with_index
1.128 with_enumerate
1.692 with_index
```

So here two takeaways for everyone reading this:

- I don't wanna say my solution is faster, I just wanted to say that from an algorithmic point of view (on an abstract mathematical level) it is the fasted soltion. Execution times on a real-world machine do not always reflect that due to a number of reasons (C code vs. Python code, other stuff running etc.) so you always wanna do some measurements for your use cases
- Be careful with how you setup your performance tests as you may introduce some bias by (accidentally) setting up your test data to yield your (expected) result: I've shown two completely different results for the same algorithm, just by varying the input.

### Original answer

Both implementations are odd if you ask me. Why not use `enumerate()` and store the position in the dictionary? then return immediately once you have a match in the dictionary. There's no point in always iterating over the whole array except wasting compute resources. Also you do not need the parameter `n` so remove it.

The worst case runtime (in case there is no repeating element or the repeating element is the last element) will be `O(n)`. Depending on how long the array is and how the values are distributed the average runtime should be (considerably) faster.

FYI: solutions utilizing `count()` will have a worst case runtime of `O(n²)` since `count()` itself takes `O(n)`. The same holds true for solutions utilzing `index()`.

```py
class Solution:
    #Function to return the position of the first repeating element.
    def firstRepeated(self, arr):
        encountered_elements = {}
        for i, value in enumerate(arr):
            if value in encountered_elements:
                return (encountered_elements[value], i)
            encountered_elements[value] = i
        return -1
        
solution = Solution()
print(solution.firstRepeated([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])) # (0, 1)
print(solution.firstRepeated([1, 2, 1, 3, 4])) # (0, 2)
print(solution.firstRepeated([1, 2, 3, 4, 1])) # (0, 4)
print(solution.firstRepeated([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) # -1
```

This function returns the two positions of the first repeating element. You can easily adjust it to return only the first/ second position of the repeating element.

Comment: Fails for example input `[10, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]`, reporting the 3 instead of the 5.

Comment: *"O(n²) [...] for solutions utilzing index()"* - It's O(n), since index() is called only once. And likely that's actually *faster* than using enumerate() (at least it was when I compared that in the past).

Comment: index()-using code being [~twice as fast](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZJNTsMwEIUllj6Fl3aURIm6QUicpKosqx5TS7UTuWN-hLgAV2DTDRyK0zBxIBhRlQWzsuU3z--z5-VtfMDdEI7H14S2uXy_eLZx8BydB-78OETMa8YMWH7ncKcgJA9RIwgdo7xinArCdkgBIYJRsAcPAQ_8mj8-5VM7RO5qfqv3iUwDP-UwlbOl5rfjt3KqCJjiaeE622wW-RkNpXSssGv6AtUFA_d_Yx4AhVxIFwTq-ycbObRzhtwrzwK12phSVwCRD8VcV1GHGxB9RyVr3m0YsylsJ4SfP1sX-KQhKDvlnsUVX81hkfqm2SjY1SRbbim-1uZXzNsxuoAiUn4jxNzfoKz6ruYrSmVbpYL2oJScR_JzMr8m9AM)

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the points you raised, which are absolutely valid, but I think as they stand in the comment section need some clarification.

Comment: The problem spec says *"the index of its first occurrence should be the smallest"*. For [10, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6], the index for the first occurrence of 5 is smaller than the index of the first occurrence of 3. That example was btw taken from the [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-first-repeating-element-array-integers/) website (though looks like they copied the problem text from the [practice](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/first-repeating-element4018/1) page, where it differs a bit (but not in this regard)).

Comment: *"you are already storing the encountered values, why not also store their position then?"* - Because it's wasteful. Creating/handling/storing the positions costs extra time and memory, it's not free.

Comment: Ok, as stated on the GFG website I think its clearer than stated by OP and it seems that my interpretation is not the correct one. I thought in regard to *first occurrence* that in this case `[1, 5, 4, 5, 5]` the desired result is `3`, not `4`. As for your second point, yes, of course you have a time-memory tradeoff, as always. Mine using more memory, yours using more time for large `n` in worst case (as shown by my last measurements). That only confirms what I said: the fastest in terms of complexity and the real-world might differ. Never claimed it was the most memory-efficient solution.

Comment: It should return 1 (index of 5), right?

Comment: You're right my benchmark case was bad, the duplicates should be at the end. In the past cases I'm sure I did it properly, I was sloppy here (I guess since I didn't really want to do it again at all :-). The Python index function with enumerate () doesn't make sense, though. The whole point was to **not** use enumerate() and to **not** create/handle **all** indexes (since that's wasteful, as you only really need **one**, if at all).

Comment: Yeah, 100% agree. Just needed an Python implementation instead of C implementation to highlight my point. It's become a very *hypothetical* / theoretical post, I guess, which was not originally planned ;)

Comment: So *"yours using more time for large n in worst case (as shown by my last measurements)"* is misleading, as that's very much not mine.

Comment: Yes, I guess it could be misleading. To state explicitly what I meant and not put words in your mouth: An algorithm following your idea i. e. using a linear search (which `index()` does) to find the index instead of looking up the index (as an algorithm following my idea would do) when we don't have a speed difference due to interpreted vs. compiled code being executed.  Again, I am not stating mine is the fastest solution when being implemented/ executed in Python (where you can of course leverage the fast list methods implemented in C).

Comment: I also should've used my standard more proper timing, using more repetitions and better statistics for more stable/reliable results, giving results like `695.1 ± 7.5 μs  with_index`, `896.3 ± 7.3 μs  with_enumerate` (for the proper input data). Those links just tend to quickly get too long for comments (since it's longer code and my preferred site encodes the code in the link).

Comment: [Link](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVNLTuQwEF2w8ylqh43SUUejQdASJ4miyOqUwRriRHaFj1p9B_Zs2Mzs2bOaA8wB5jTY1el0EAgW1NJ-9fzeq_Ljn_6erjr39PR7ILM4-3_0YHzXAtkWwbZ95wl69KZed4Mj9KAD3wlGBdJkA9l12GNb1C6L5w3eCNGggVtLVzW6oUWvCaX2Xq0ExEI3UmJT4zW26CjABWy2fGs6DzaDG309RB0OPmJIZc0c857xgEzlkQb_MbBkmmqCf4KJKq2Y0S2KmVXrGrz72mZAkmpyOlmIfd_0FhnynQbuVZ8aynXTzHEzQ5EnyixPvHaXKItlLJXBeaxKCDO4dXLxdrjZLAEh0pbwQM0KyoptmuSEe7ccWFqfIM2YFOdSEpxAgaeMp4QPca2wkUxXmkqVq2JZVXO55niT1k5SUKufeWG28PcZNryDfPaDz_69BDgWibZOtJOv8fW3-g7R0jKqSo_LQ5SG53uAjNJy3ffodlKlgkXsVWLiHX0wfQa_8P6C7Y_P9946kvtAMjB5XTvdYl2r3ccc_-f-n74C)

Comment: Yeah, I mean of course that would be more scientifically accurate, but I'd say let's not overcomplicate this more than we've already done ;) Not unlikely that `n` will be so small the difference won't matter for OP and also more than likely your solution (and yes, here I mean exactly your solution leveraging `index()`) is faster being executed in a real-world environment for most common `n` (an engineer's point of view). The whole point of my edit was pointing out that my claim is correct from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: *"I am guessing [n] is supposed to be the array size"* - It is: *"Given an array arr[] of size n"*.

Comment: They can't remove it, as then the solution doesn't get accepted anymore (causes a runtime error).

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised these work, especially as `arr.index(i)` will go into the array to find the first index again, not the next

Possibly this could be simplified as

```py
def solution(array):
    for index, value in enumerate(array):
        try:
            array[index+1:].index(value)  # slice to check the rest
        except ValueError:  # didn't find value in the rest of the list
            continue
        return index
    return -1
```

Some test cases to consider

```py
assert solution([1])       == -1  # not enough values
assert solution([1,2])     == -1  # no matches
assert solution([1,2,3,2]) ==  1  # simple duplicate
assert solution([2,3,2])   ==  0  # simple duplicate
assert solution([2,3,3,2]) ==  0  # inner duplicate(s)
```

**Snippet 1**

This doesn't get the index, but a count, so it should at least iterate over `m`, not `arr` (assuming you're using a newer Python which orders dict)

**Snippet 2**

This is very inefficient as it repeatedly iterates over the array internally `if i not in arr:` to check for membership (though `i` is guaranteed to be a member already)

Comment: *"I'm surprised these work"* - What makes you think they do?

Comment: Why should snippet 1 iterate over m, not arr?

Comment: @KellyBundy oh, simply their wording _"Code snippet 2 runs just fine but not code snippet 1"_, to me means that one of them at least runs and passes their brief testing or whatever GFG test cases exist (though that may not be the case) - there's surely a variety of ways to slice this problem (ha), especially if there's a follow-up variant like the first or exactly `n` duplicates (currently an unused arg??)